# Elasticsearch ordering by field value which is not in the filter

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, boost

can somebody help me please to make a query which will order result items according some field value if this field is not part of query in request. I have a query:

```
{
    "_source": [
        "ico",
        "name",
        "city",
        "status"
    ],
    "sort": {
        "_score": "desc",
        "status": "asc"
    },
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "normalized": {
                            "query": "idona",
                            "analyzer": "standard",
                            "boost": 3
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "normalized2": {
                            "value": "idona",
                            "boost": 2
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "normalized": "idona"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The result is sorted according field status alphabetically ascending. Status contains few values like [active, canceled, old....] and I need something like boosting for every possible values in query. E.g. active boost 5, canceled boost 4, old boost 3 ........... Is it possible to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a [custom sort using script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) to achieve what you want.

I've just made use of generic `match_all` query for my query, you can probably go ahead and add your query logic there, but the solution that you are looking for is in the `sort` section of the below query.

Make sure that `status` is a [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) type

### Custom Sorting Based on Values

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "match_all":{  

      }
   },
   "sort":[  
      { "_score": "desc" }, 
      {  
         "_script":{  
            "type":"number",
            "script":{  
               "lang":"painless",
               "inline":"if(params.scores.containsKey(doc['status'].value)) { return params.scores[doc['status'].value];} return 100000;",
               "params":{  
                  "scores":{  
                     "active":5,
                     "old":4,
                     "cancelled":3
                  }
               }
            },
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

In the above query, go ahead and add the values in the `scores` section of the query. For e.g. if your value is `new` and you want it to be at say value `2`, then your scores would be in the below:

```
{  
   "scores":{  
      "active":5,
      "old":4,
      "cancelled":3,
      "new":6
   }
}
```

So basically the documents would first get sorted by `_score` and then on that sorted documents, the [script sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) would be executed.

Note that the script sort is `desc` by nature as I understand that you would want to show `active` documents at the top, followed by other values. Feel free to play around with it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Camo, was the above answer useful? Is that what you were looking for or do you have any further queries!!??

Comment: Looks fine, but I am lost in it for now.

Comment: Now i have another problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468387/elasticsearch-how-to-make-shorter-phrase-more-relevant-in-result